# How do I free memory faster?

Tags: c#, list, memory-management, garbage-collection

I´m currently working on an app where I need do search a list of elements from a REST API service. But every time I do the search the memory usage keeps going up and up and up.

Everytime I do the search, I do the following steps:
1. I clean the list 
2. I call a method brings me the list from the request from the REST API
2. I set the list by calling the request method

```
myList.clear();
myList = GetListFromREST("https://myrestapi.com/itemList");

async Task<List<Item>> GetListFromREST(string url)
{
    List<Item> result;
    var response = await new RestService<Response>().GetDataAsyc(url);

    if (response.Error.StatusCode == 200)
    {
        result = response.Data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

According to memory diagnosing tool memory is always going up and up and up. It doesn´t make sense to me because when I do the clear it must be restored.

[image: Every time I do a search memory goes up and never is restore]

Comment: Unless you have a memory problem dont worry about it, though if you really do want to, dont allocate as much... The fact is .net doesnt aggressive garbage collect and give back memory to the operating system unless there is a need

Comment: As a side note, always use the `using` statement where you can. Though this wont inherently save you allocations but is a smart thing to do anyway

Comment: Does `response` implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: @mjwillis no, response doesn't implement `IDisposable`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the Performance Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/
Just to make sure there even is a problem that needs fixing.

As for the Memory Consumption, there are two issues:

1. It is really hard to [measure reliably](https://www.itwriting.com/dotnetmem.php). But your measuring tool does sound more reliable.
2. You propably do not have a Problem, just normal working of the GC.

Your Memory is managed by the Garbage Collector. The GC's work takes time, during wich all other Threads have to be halted. It is also way to valuable a Productivity Multiplier to work without, so this is just a price you pay. However due to the performance impact, the garbage collector prefers not to run *unessesarily*. Indeed if it only runs once on application closure, that is the **ideal scenario**.

Nothing short of a explicit call or the *danger* of a OutOfMemory exception will get it to run earlier. If you ever do run into a OOM, you can be sure of one thing: Everything that could be collected, has been collected.

If after all this you still need to improove stuff after all this, a Managed Runtime like .NET was propably the wrong starting point to begin with. Your propably might even go all the way into Realtime Programming. But considering that you are retrieving data from a WEB API, I am going to say that with 99.99% propability the network is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please make sure you have a problem with memory consumption. What if you run your code fragment 100 or 1000 times? Will the level of consumed memory stabilize  or it grows constantly? You only have a problem if it grows unlimited.

In case your memory consumption stabilizes at some level, you don't have a memory leak and therefore shouldn't be "resolving" this issue.

Second, it seems to me that calling

```
myList.Clear();
```

doesn't make any sense. On the next line you assign a new value to the reference, so if no other alive object in the system keeps reference to your list, the old list goes out of scope and memory can be reclaimed by the GC.

Third, with every call to *GetListFromREST* you create a new instance of *RestService* object. When the method returns this object gets out of scope and can be reclaimed, but you create some pressure on the GC anyway. Of course, GC doesn't collect all unused objects right away, therefore memory consumption can grow even if objects go out of scope quickly. In case your *RestService* uses *HttpClient* under the hood, you should think about keeping it alive as it's recommended to reuse HttpClient object instead of constant recreation.